# Delete a owl slide with laravel, vue.js and axios

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, axios, owl-carousel

I have a nice little slider, it shows images with some text to page visitors. It uses owl carousel within a vue component, and basically works as expected. I am trying to add a delete button, so that the user that created the slider can delete the image if they don't like it or whatever.

I started with the controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Slide $slide)
{
    $slide = Slide::where('id', $request->id);
    $slide->delete();

    return response()->json($slide, 200);
}
```

I have route groups
**Edited**

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/{area}'], function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
            Route::post('/{hustle}', 'Slides\SlideController@save')->name('slide.save');
            Route::delete('/{hustle}/slider/{slide}', 'Slides\SlideController@destroy')->name('slide.destroy');
        });
Route::get('/{hustle}/slider', 'Hustle\SliderController@index');
    });
```

The button itself looks just like this

```
 <button @click="deleteSlide">Delete</button> {{ slider.uid }}
```

and finally the method

**Edited**

```
methods: {
  getSlider () {
    var that = this;
    axios.get( '/' + this.areaId + '/' + this.hustleId + '/slider').then((response) => {
      that.sliders = response.data;
      console.log(that.sliders);
      Vue.nextTick(function() {

        $('#sliders').owlCarousel({
          items:1,
        });

      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      this.errored = true
    });
  },

  deleteSlide (slider) {
    var that = this;
    axios.delete('/' + this.areaId + '/' + this.hustleId + '/slider/' + this.sliderId).then((response) => {
      that.slider.splice(slider, 1)
      console.log(that.sliderId);
    });

  }
},
```

All I get for an error is 500 bad method call, even with, the debug bar also gives a bad method call.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough rep to comment but...

At first glance your route takes two paramters: hustle and slide.
And youre passing 4 parameters to axios: area, hustle, a slider string and an id

So thats a completely different route :)

Comment: It is nested within another route group {area}, I was missing the string tho, nice catch. Still not completely correct tho, I got the correct response tho.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help

Comment: Sorry Marina, I am still getting a method not allowed error. The typo was correct, but there is still something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the complete route file and the updated code for the axios call?

Comment: I have done some editing added the rest of the routes, and added all the methods included in the component.